# Get BASE-HREF in APP_INITIALIZER

Tags: angular

I need to parse url in APP_INITIALIZER. To parse it properly I need to have access to BASE_HREF in it. 
Is it possible?

In current approach 'getImportantFromUrl' parse url incorrectly, cause do not now anything about base-href

```js
// =====================
{
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeApp,
      deps: [...]
}
// =====================
export function initializeApp(...){
   return () =>{
     new Promise<any>((resolve: any) => {
         const locationInitialized = injector.get(LOCATION_INITIALIZED, 
             Promise.resolve(null));
         locationInitialized.then((x) => {
             // todo: getImportantFromUrl should parse url taking in account base-href
             var x = getImportantFromUrl(window.location.pathname);
}
};
```

Comment: Have you considered storing the base href in environment.ts? You can set the value as part of the build process via the CLI tools and it would make it a lot easier to access in the initializer.

Comment: @Brandon is it possible to get access to enviroment.ts from APP_INITIALIZER?

Comment: `environment` is just a constant, so you should be able to import that from anywhere in the application at any point.